# authenticating using google API instead of OpenID

Tags: google-app-engine, authentication, openid

I have a need to authenticate users using their gmail ID. However I need to do this without redirecting to google's login page as with OpenID.

Is it possible to do it using an API call ? Does google provide such and authentication API?

Thanks,
Murtaza

Comment: How are you wanting to authentic them? I.e. how will they prove that they own the gmail address?

Comment: They will enter their username / password on my login page. I will then call gmail API to authenticate the username / password.

Comment: You might be able to verify through some type of SMTP call, but I don't know if that will work on GAE. Out of curiosity why don't you want to use OAuth or Google login? I don't think very many users will want to give you there email and password.

Comment: These are all internal apps. We use google apps for our email. We also have external customers for which we have creates custom IDs. Now the requirement is to create a central login page for all apps. And I dont want to redirect the user twice, after he has already been redirected to the central login page. When the user enters his email, I will check if it is of google apps, and authenticate him through API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such API. There should not be such an API.

The redirect to the Google login page happens for several very good reasons. It lets the user know exactly what is happening. They know that you are authenticating against their Gmail Id.

It provides a layer of security between applications that use the Gmail Id and the user who provides the Gmail Id. If the user provided the username and password directly to you, they have no way of knowing that you won't hang on to that information and do something evil or stupid with it.

Providing that kind of access would assist a malicious programmer in silently using brute force to crack some other user's password. There's no way for an API to prevent a malicious programmer from entering some random person's Gmail address and trying any number of passwords very efficiently.

So, you can either accept the redirect or you can roll your own username and password system that is unrelated to Gmail.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just use the User API?  It's well documented.  The drawback is that you must login with a gmail id.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/users/

Comment: The other drawback is that using the Users API involves a redirect to the Google login page which is what he is explicitly trying to avoid.